# how to keyword search in the list of installed package?

Tags: debian, dpkg

the background question is:
i am trying to listing any packages that related to 'using multiple display manager'

what is the most efficient way to use essential command, so i get most readable result to solve my [main-question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577523/how-to-restore-an-active-x-server-session) ?

as far to my knowledge the essential command is dpkg and dpkg-query.

Comment: Hello. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/577515/edit) to provide an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry this is side-question, which more importantly to solve my [main-question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577523/how-to-restore-an-active-x-server-session)

Comment: Either this question stands alone or it's not a useful question. Please [edit] the question to provide the necessary detail

Comment: thank you, kindly help me on my main question :(

Comment: I'm trying to answer _this_ question, but it's incomplete and lacking sufficient detail. Right now I've voted to close it because of these issues.

Comment: you have your reason, but if we can chat perhaps I will able to fill the lacking sufficient detail. :)

Answer (score 1):

The following command should do the trick:

```
dpkg -l | grep "using multiple display manager"
```